# Jupyter Notebook autocompletion with special characters

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am testing a customized autocompletion in Jupyter like

```
from IPython import get_ipython

def my_completer(ipython, event):
    word = event.line.strip().split()[-1]
        
    result = ['testaa','test_bb','test-cc','test*a', 'test:b']
    return result

ipython = get_ipython()
ipython.set_hook('complete_command', my_completer, re_key='test.*')
```

This works quite well. When I type in a cell `test` and press TAB I can have all the choices. If I type `testa` and then TAB I obtain correctly `testaa`, the same with `test_` that returns `test_bb`.

But when I try to add one between `-`, `*` or `:` the completion fails because these characters are interpreted as operations in Python and not as a part of the word. Is there a way to overwrite this behaviour or at least to present the existing choice in the list of options that appears?

I verified that the function `my_completer` is correctly called and the result is returned, the problem seems in the way Jupyter see the text in the cell.

Answer (score 0):

After a discussion with one of the maintainer of IPython I find a workaround for this and it is explained in this issue: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/13618

I leave it here just if someone else has the same problem.